# Eclipse- How to change Linkcolor for Dark Theme

Tags: eclipse

I use a Dark-Theme for Eclipse. But in the Pereferences-Menu, the links are dark-blue (nearly not readable). Even some Plugins (like dbeaver) have same Linkcolors inside.

[image]
[image]

Where can i adjust this color?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts
- Then type "link" at the filter field and try to change it

Comment: I Try it, didn't work. I change the Color to Green, and restart eclipse, Links are still darkblue

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It´s a systemwide setting (link color). If your on Windows 10, you can throw your PC out the window, create a class action law suit to make Microsoft create a design with 0000FF as link color, or turn on "high" contrast mode under

Personalization > Colors > High Contrast

(I´m not using an english machine. Path might be called differently.)